# Broken VBA Loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I'm sure this is simple I just can't find anything on the Web.

I'm writing a Macro to format XL spreadsheets that i download from a 3rd party application. They come formatted all wacky so i'm trying to make it easier to get the data we need from them.

This is a simple VBA Do Loop that causes the cells in Column BL to update. The data in these cells contain line breaks which don't show up until you double click in the cell. The VBA below causes an update to the cells which achieves the same effect, just with less work. However it is currently crashing excel and I can't figure out why. It works in a single instance, but when I loop -- BOOM!!! -- frozen. Any help would be gently appreciated.

```
Sub updateCell()

    Dim currentValue As String
    ActiveSheet.Range("BL1").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        currentValue = ActiveCell().Value
        ActiveCell().Value = currentValue & ""
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems likely that what you think are empty cells, are not in fact empty, and the symptom you describe is simply what happens when Excel tries to iterate each of 1.048,576 cells in the column.  Try `Do Until Trim(ActiveCell.Value) = ""` maybe?

Comment: You may also want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) about how (and why) to avoid relying on `Activate` and `Select` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something a bit more direct:

```
With ActiveSheet 
    lrow = .Range("BL" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '~~> find last row on BL
    With .Range("BL1:BL" & lrow) '~~> work on the target range
        .Value = .Value '~~> assign its current value to it
    End With
End With
```

Above code is like manually pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Edit1:** Explanation on getting the last row

```
ActiveSheet.Rows.Count '~~> Returns the number of rows in a sheet which is 1048576
MsgBox ActiveSheet.Rows.Count '~~> run this to confirm
```

So this line actually concatenates *BL* to *1048576*.

```
.Range("BL" & .Rows.Count) '~~> Count is a property of the Rows Collection
```

Same as:

```
.Range("BL" & 1048576)
```

And same as:

```
.Range("BL1048576")
```

Then to get to the last row, we use *Range Object End Method*.

```
.Range("BL" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

So basically, above code go to *Cell BL1048576* then like manually pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Up</kbd>.
To return the actual row number of the range, we use the *Range Object Row property*.

```
lrow = .Range("BL" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

[*See here more about **With** Statement*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).
It has the same effect (with your code) without the loop. HTH

But if what you want is to remove *Line Breaks* produced by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on a cell, try below:

```
Dim lrow As Long, c As Range
With ActiveSheet
    lrow = .Range("BL" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In .Range("BL1:BL" & lrow)
        c.Value = Replace(c.Value, Chr(10), "")
    Next
End With
```

Where `Chr(10)` is the equivalent of *Line Break* replaced with `""` using *Replace Function*.

Comment: You'll get a type mismatch error on this. Why not simply `.Value` = `.Value`?

Comment: @DavidZemens Ah I posted it without testing. I just copied what OP posted, hold on a sec I'll change it. But I'm not sure if it will get the result the OP wanted.

Comment: I think it will. Not quite sure why OP is deliberately appending a null string to each cell's `.Value`, seems like pointless operation.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yeah, regardless I provided another solution that hopefully will get what OP wants.

Comment: This should work. I need the line breaks, they just don't appear in the cell by default. I have to cause an update to the cell to make the line breaks visable. Many thanks to all the posters.

Comment: @JamieMarshall See my edit. As for the *With Statement*, you can browse the link. Basically it is way of assessing multiple property of an object.

Comment: Thanks, I understand with statements just fine, it's how you found the lrow that confused me. I have it now though. A truly elegant solution to my problem. Instead of looping through the row, you re-wrote its values as properties of an entire row. Clever.